# Is there any value in expressing real numbers as rotations around the unit circle in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, rotations

I have no math experience or education, so please let me know if this is useless. But I realized you could express real numbers as rotations. Here’s my thought process.

Real Rotation

Real numbers can be thought of as rotations around the unit circle, with a single rotation equaling the unit. Any real number x can then be expressed in the form e^(x2 πi) on the complex plane. Positive numbers rotate counter-clockwise a certain number of times (or alternatively a certain number of revolutions per second), and negative numbers rotate in the opposite direction. This is real rotation.

To represent imaginary numbers using real rotation, you would simply replace x with yi. Any imaginary number is expressed in the form e^(yi(2 πi)) which simplifies to e^(-2 πy). This of course cannot be graphed on the complex plane except as a 1-d position on the real number line, but it can be represented on the real plane as an exponential function. Imaginary numbers in real rotation decay extremely rapidly for higher values of y, and grow rapidly in the negative direction for lower values of y.

Complex numbers can also be represented through real rotation in the form e^((ai+b)(2 πi)) which simplifies to (e^(-2 πa))*(e^(2 πib)). b thus determines rotation, and a determines magnitude of the unit circle. For higher values of a the magnitude shrinks rapidly, whereas for lower values it grows rapidly.

---

Again, I just did this for fun, but I’m wondering if it’s at all useful. I find it interesting that imaginary and real numbers swap coordinate planes, but complex numbers stay where they are (though their behavior changes dramatically.)

Comment: Essentially (if I understand you correctly) you’ve defined a function $\phi$ which takes a real number $x$ to the point $e^{2\pi i x}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. The main issue I see is that this map is not invertible; for example, $\phi(0)=\phi(1)$, so we can’t recover the original real number if we just know the rotated point in the complex plane. However, look up “quotient spaces” in topology - you may be interested. In particular, you can identify the quotient space of $[0,1]$ with $0$ and $1$ identified as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @csch2 Why does phi(o) = phi(1)? Wouldn’t phi(0) be 1, or the resting position on the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, and $\phi(1)=e^{2\pi i}=1$ as well, since a rotation by $2\pi$ radians is equivalent to not rotating at all.

Comment: @csch2 Oh yes. That’s correct which is why there needs to be some sort of way to track the rotations. I was thinking of larger  numbers as either multiple rotations or as a higher angular velocity. Both require a time function so yes this would not work out with just a graph, you’d need to observe the rotation in some way too.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe instead, then, you'd want to identify $x$ with the function $\phi_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $\phi_x(t)=\exp(2\pi i x t)$. Each of these functions is what's called a _character_ of $\mathbb{R}$, and they come into play all the time in a field of math called Fourier analysis. You might like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) to see how they're used!

Comment: An example of using complex numbers to represent rotations in a plane geometry problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980521/how-far-would-rebecca-walk-if-she-walks-100-feet-in-a-straight-line-and-turns-1/3981716#3981716